# Rhino stub not matching expectation

Tags: unit-testing, rhino-mocks, stub

I am stubbing two different objects.  Here are the interfaces:

```cs
public IInterface1
{
    IEnumerable<Foo> Method1(int p1, string p2 = null, string p3 = null);
}

public IInterface2
{
    Bar Method2(int p3, int? p4 = null);
}
```

As you can see, both have parameters that default to null.  However, one is matching my `Expect`, and the other isn't.  This stub works; when its method is called with a value matching `testData.p1`, it returns an array of two `Foo`s:

```cs
var obj1 = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IInterface1>();
obj1.Expect(m => m.Method1(
         Arg.Is(testData.p1), 
         Arg<string>.Is.Null, 
         Arg<string>.Is.Null))
    .Return(new[] { new Foo(), new Foo() });
```

However, this similar stub is *not* returning the expected result, returning `null` instead, despite the parameters matching the expectation:

```cs
var obj2 = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IInterface2>();
obj2.Expect(m => m.Method2(Arg.Is(testData.p3), Arg<int?>.Is.Null))
    .Return(new Bar());
```

Why is this second stub not matching on my parameters?  Even if I use `Arg<int?>.Is.Anything` for the second expected parameter, `null` is still returned.

**Update**

OK, I found an alternate way to set up my expectation, passing the expected values instead of using `Arg`:

```cs
obj1.Expect(m => m.Method1(testData.p1, null, null))
    .Return(new[] { new Foo(), new Foo() });

obj2.Expect(m => m.Method2(testData.p3, null))
    .Return(new Bar());
```

Both stubs return the expected results when I set them up this way.  I'm still unclear on the distinction and why one worked with `Arg` and the other didn't.  I suppose this is yet another time where I'm getting confused about the mixing of AAA, record/replay, mocks, and stubs in this library.  Can anyone dispel my confusion about why the original code didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At runtime, when you pass a null to the second parameter of `IInterface2`, .NET will create a `Nullable<int>` and pass that to your method implementation.  Your implementation code can then check p4.HasValue and do whatever you want to account for null values.

But from Rhino.Mocks standpoint, when it intercepts the method call, it's going to see that the second parameter is a `Nullable<int>` (not a null instance) and therefore you won't match on your expectation.

In the second attempt, when you pass null directly, the runtime will, again, wrap that null up in a `Nullable<T>`. Rhino.Mocks will check the two parameters for equality (to see if you have a matching expectation).  `Nullable<T>` overrides the `Equals` method to check if both of the `Nullable<T>`'s have null and will return true -- thus matching your expectation.

Comment: Oh, I finally get it.  The reason why `Arg<int?>.Is.Null` doesn't match and `Arg<string>.Is.Null` does is because `Nullable<int>` is a *value type* (I thought it was a reference type).  Therefore, the direct comparison doesn't work, whereas the C# compiler wraps the `null` for a `Nullable<int>` parameter into a `Nullable<int>` value.  Am I understanding correctly?